# Capybara - Click element by class name

Tags: ruby, automation, capybara

For what seems to be a simple question I've been on this for a stupidly long time and can't seem to find anything on Google. I have this button I need to click which has no id but a class is included

```
<button class="filter-case-studies" onclick="initBootpag(filterForContentType('CASE STUDIES', searchHits))" type="button">
<b>CASE STUDIES</b>
(2)
</button>
```

I've tried using `click_on` which I now know is only for links and buttons so of course won't work. This is what I have so far:

```
When(/^I filter the results to only see case studies$/) do
  click_on('filter-case-studies')
end
```

I've also tried `page.find('filter-case-studies').click`, this too doesn't work.

`page.find(:class, 'filter-case-studies').click` defualts to :css so this also failed for me.

Is there no way to click an element by the class name in Capybara?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The standard way of doing this in Capybara is

```
find('button.filter-case-studies').click
```

In relatively recent versions of Capybara you should also be able to do

```
click_on(class: 'filter-case-studies')
```

Comment: Just to complement this answer: the `click_on` method only works for buttons or links. If you are looking to click on other elements, then you should do a `find(...).click`

Answer (score 4):

`find('.filter-case-studies').click` as recommended here https://robots.thoughtbot.com/write-reliable-asynchronous-integration-tests-with-capybara#find-the-first-matching-element

Answer (score 0):

I had a button that could not be found (`Unable to find visible link or button nil with classes [close-modal]`) using the methods above.

This worked for me: `page.execute_script('$.find(".close-modal")[0].click()')`

Answer (score -1):

`click_on('.filter-case-studies')`

You need the `.` selector for classes, and `#` for ids.

Comment: Ah I see what they mean by :css selectors now. That seems to have almost worked but now I get an error saying `Element is not clickable at point (914.2666625976562, 16.133331298828125). Other element would receive the click: <div class="top-navbar   ng-scope" ng-controller="menuCtrl"></div> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)` Since the navbar is absolute it must be getting in the way

Comment: `click_on` doesn't take a CSS selector, it takes the id, contained text, alt, title, etc - so this example should not work

Comment: It's true, I had to use `page.find(:class, '.filter-case-studies').click` for it to work. I'll post a proper solution

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to  Mr Schutte for the idea to use `.` selectors.

I had to use `page.find(:class, '.filter-case-studies').click` in the end. The absolute navbar got in the way of the button so I then had to include `page.execute_script "window.scrollBy(0,500)"` to complete the test.

Comment: `:class` isn't a selector type provided by Capybara so the example you show wouldn't work unless you had registered a custom selector type.

Comment: Actually depending on the version of Capybara you are using it may either just ignore the `:class` parameter and default to :css, or it will output a warning about an 'Unknown selector type' and then default to :css .  Also depending on the page, increasing the page size may remove the need for scrolling the page.